# How to get require.context to work with Create React App with/withou Craco?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, create-react-app, craco

I'm trying to do some requires during runtime through `require.context` in my CRA (with Typescript) project, but I'm only getting these kinds of errors:

> TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function

and

> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

I read somewhere that this now needs to be polyfilled through Babel or `cra-rewired`. Well I'm already using Craco to enable Less-support, but I have no idea how to add `require.context` to my Craco configs.

Anyone know how to do this?

**Update:** This is how I'm calling require.context:

```
const packagesDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '../../../../packages');
const textDataContext = require.context(packagesDirectory, true, /(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(mdx?)/);
```

**Update 2:**

As some of the comments in [this thread](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/2487) suggest, I've tried adding `babel-plugin-require-context-hook` to my app like so:

```
// craco.config.js

const CracoLessPlugin = require('craco-less');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {plugin: CracoLessPlugin}
    ],
    babel: {
        plugins: ['require-context-hook']
    }
};
```

And then I've tried calling `require.context` like so:

```
// myfile.js

import registerRequireContextHook from 'babel-plugin-require-context-hook/register';
registerRequireContextHook();

const packagesDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '../../../../packages');
const textDataContext = require.context(packagesDirectory, true, /(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(mdx?)/);
```

But then I get this error:

> TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function

**Update 3:**

It seems CRA **does** support require.context without the need for any polyfills at all. But it looks like it fails when it is executed through an imported module. In my previous attempts I have been executing calls to `require.context` in `myfile.js` (see above) which has been imported by `index.js` like so:

```
// index.js

import myModules from 'myfile.js';

ReactDOM.render(...);
```

However, if I change `index.js` to this:

```
// index.js

const something = require.context('../../packages/', true, /(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(mdx?)/);
something.keys().forEach(key => console.log(key));

ReactDOM.render(...);
```

It works like a charm! **Why?!**

Comment: Did you write the require.context call correctly? Cause this type of error often due to incorrect function call. Provide some code.

Comment: Updated question with code 

Comment: try `import '@babel/polyfill';` like here https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/4479#issuecomment-435611229

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Require.context` it is a webpack feature, not `cra` or something else.

### So why it doesn't work with your `upd1` or `upd2` and it does with `upd3`?

The answer is pretty simple - because variable is used here. Webpack needs your code to be statically analyzable. It means that when you write for example `require.context('../src/directory/', true, /.ts$/)` webpack thinks hmmm OK I need to find and prepare all `.ts` files in `src/directory` recursively because it can be used in further steps.

And it can't work with variables because `require.context(myPathVariable, true, /.ts$/)` can be anything. Webpack don't know what `myPathVariable` is at `build` phase because it will be calculated at `runtime` phase only.

This rule is also about `dynamic imports`. `import('../src/keks/index.ts')` will work, `import(myVar + '../src/keks/index.ts')` will not.

Please see this [issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4772) with discussion and some tips about `require.context` "staticness".

### How to get dynamic paths working

One way to use dynamic paths is to use `DefinePlugin`. But all of your dynamic paths should be known and calculated at `build` phase (in webpack config or any node.js script).
Example:
`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [new DefinePlugin({ PACKAGES_DIR: JSON.stringify('path/to/packages') })]
}
```

and then:
`index.ts`
you can use `require.context(PACKAGES_DIR, true, /\.ts$/)` or `import(PACKAGES_DIR + 'myfile.ts')` because webpack already know something about this paths.

Comment: Thanks, looks like you're right! Bounty is all yours :) Frustrating how hard this was to figure out. I think the `TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function` error was caused by a missing `@types/webpack-env` dependency however. Oh lord, deliver me from people who design incomprehensible error messages!